# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS }

Tags: java, android

I m using simple code as below to take permission for changing ringer during DND. App is being tested on Android 6.0. But it is crashing with below log

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS }
```

Here is my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (!notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
    }
}
```

Which I m calling on button click.

Comment: While they do not mention it on that particular action in the JavaDocs, you should assume that this activity is optional on any given device (or, at least, this `Intent` action may not be supported on any given device).

Comment: @CommonsWare, I think u right. I should just go ahead with try to handle crash.

Comment: did not find any solution of this issue???

Answer (score 0):

try this code snippet it worked for me [image: android code]

and yes don't forget to add permission in manifest ...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>

Comment: Please avoid posting images of code. You could simply copy/paste your code here...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (!notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just surround with try n catch.
Worked for me

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                    && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }catch (Exception et){
                            //tell user something went wrong
                        }
    }
```